# Query takes lot of time to process a single line command need help to optimizing it

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$Loc" -Recurse -Include *.cfg,*.bat,*.xml,*.properties,*.ini,*.config -Exclude *.dll,*.log,*.exe,*log*.txt,*.tmp,*.mdb,*.mdf,*.edb,*.dat,*.zip,*.pem,*.ldf |
    Select-String -Pattern "password=" |
    Select-String -Pattern "pass=" |
    Select-String -Pattern "passwd=" |
    Select-String -Pattern "passphrase=" |
    Select-String -Pattern "pass=" |
    Select-String -Pattern "pwd=" |
    Select-String -Pattern "psw=" |
    Select-String -Pattern "<password>" |
    Select-Object Path, Filename, Pattern, LineNumber, Line
```

I am trying to search for patterns like above in all the files present in the D drive. It takes lot of time to process it. Is it possible to reduce the time involved by optimizing the query above?

Comment: You should combine the patterns separated via `|` in one pattern string. However, if drive D has many files then Get-ChildItem will be inherently slow and there's nothing you can do about it except reading the drive's MFT or USN journal directly or maybe use [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)'s API.

Answer (score 2):

The include extensions implicitly exclude the others,
so no need to use the `-Exclude` parameter at all.

```
$Extensions = @('*.cfg','*.bat','*.xml','*.properties','*.ini','*.config')
$ToMatch = 'password=','pass=','passwd=','passphrase=','pwd=','psw=','<‌​password>'
$Pattern = ($ToMatch | ForEach{[regex]::escape($_)}) -join '|'
$loc = [environment]::getfolderpath(“userprofile”)

# -Exclude *.dll,*.log,*.exe,*log*.txt,*.tmp,*.mdb,*.mdf,*.edb,*.dat,*.zip,*.pem,*.ldf 

Get-ChildItem -Path "$Loc\*" -Recurse -Include $Extensions |
    Select-String -Pattern $Pattern|
    Select-Object Path, Filename, Pattern, LineNumber, Line
```

**Edit** Included [@TheMadTechnician's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician) suggestion.

Comment: It's more code, but one thing that helps people make sure that they escape correctly is to define an array of strings to match, and then escape each and join them with a pipe. Such as: `$ToMatch = 'password=','pass=','passwd=','passphrase=','pwd=','psw=','<password>';
 $Pattern = ($ToMatch | ForEach{[regex]::escape($_)}) -join '|'`

Comment: Thanks . will try this

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Nice enhancement, I will incorporate it in my script.